# How to reduce processing time for multiple nested loops

Tags: python, loops, numpy, bigdata, tf-idf

We have some 40,000 rows with text (like tweets) which we are comparing based on Document term (DF-IDF) matrix. The objective is to build a simple network where there is connection between two rows if there are common words/tokens between them, say at least 'k'.

A very simple code by reading the tweets TF-IDF with twitterID is presented here:

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import csv

k = 3 # two tuples have at least three common keywords
t = []
with open('file1.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for fields in csv_reader:
        t.append(fields)

for i in range(len(t)):  # Loop 1
    j = i + 1 
    while(j<len(t)):     # Loop 2   
        commonkw = 0
        for kw in range(1, 246): # Loop 3  (column 1 is ID)
            if(int(t[i][kw]) != 0 and int(t[j][kw]) != 0):  # If both have a common keyword in the Document term matrix
                commonkw += 1
        if(commonkw >=k):
            with open("file2.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
                outputwriter = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter= ',', lineterminator='\n')
                record = [t[i][0], t[j][0],commonkw]
                outputwriter.writerow(record)
                outputfile.close()
        j += 1
```

The problem is, for suppose 400,000; the total pair-wise comparisons are n(n-1)/2
    = 80 billion. Moreover, it has to check for the term matrix (around 300 words/columns matrix)

Can the processing be improved in any ways?

We tried pandas chunkwise reading,writing and manipulations, but direct list seems to work better. We had read about reading tuples are faster than dictionaries, but what about lists?
Also, can the looping be reduced by some R type apply or iterator functions? It would be a great learning. Thanks!

The dataset looks like this: https://github.com/kartucson/pyspark_ipython/blob/master/sample_input_loops.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import csv

df_s = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',nrows=5)
df_chunks = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',dtype = df_s.dtypes,iterator=True, chunksize=500)
df = pd.concat(df_chunks, ignore_index=True)

k = 3
count = 0
for row1 in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    for row2 in range(0,df.shape[0]):
        if row2>row1:
            vec=0
            for col in range(1,df.shape[1]):
                if (df.iloc[row1,col] <> 0 and df.iloc[row2,col] <> 0):
                    vec += 1
            if vec > k:        
                with open("file2.csv", 'a') as save_file:
                            csvWriter = csv.writer(save_file)                            csvWriter.writerow([np.array(df['ID'])[row1],np.array(df['ID'])[row2],vec]) 
                            count = count + 1
                            print "row ",count
```

Comment: Would you post the pandas code? Its surprising that this is faster than pandas.

Comment: @kilojoules added the pandas code too. May be a bit elementary approach :-)